# Clusters of powerful numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A powerful number is a number that can be expressed as one number to the power of another.

- Between 120 and 130 are 3 powerful numbers.
  $121=11^2;~  125=5^3 ;~ 128=2^7$
- Between 129 and 143 there are none.

Has any work been done analysing clusters of powerful numbers?

Comment: There's [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), and you can read there about Pillai's conjecture.

Comment: Also, people tend to use a different definition of powerful numbers.

Comment: A perfect power is a number of the form $a^b$ , where $a,b>1$ are integers. This is what you mean here. A powerful number has all exponents greater than $1$ in the prime factorization , or equivalent, is a product of a perfect square and a perfect cube , one of which is allowed to be $1$.

Comment: Thanks everyone.